# Are records for Right To Know requests maintained, and are they publicly accessible?

Tags: united-states, pennsylvania

This is specifically concerning the [Right to Know](http://www.openrecords.pa.gov/RTKL/About.cfm) law in Pennsylvania.

If a person claims they have filed a Right to Know request with an agency (e.g. a police department), can evidence of that **request** be obtained by a third party?

If so, what is the proper method of obtaining this information? Is the agency to which the request was made responsible for keeping a log of requests? Are they obligated to release this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any records kept by an agency in relation to processing Right to Know requests are themselves subject to the Right to Know law. Parts of such records might be exempt from disclosure on the basis of the personal privacy of the applicant.

A common feature of Right to Know/Freedom of Information laws is that your right to access a document doesn't extend to a document that doesn't exist. That's where record-keeping laws and policies are important. I'm not aware of any law that requires Pennsylvanian agencies to keep records.